# What are the downsides to having PostgreSQL database available directly from public network?

Tags: firewalls, databases

When auditing a machine for one of my clients I noticed that they have PostgreSQL listening and accessible from public network. This is not necessary for their application, seems they simply neglected to set up the firewall properly.

PostgreSQL seems to be running default `pg_hba.conf` file from the distribution package, and it does not accept connections without valid credentials.

I still feel that it is wrong to unnecessarily expose the database to the outside world. What arguments are for/against such approach?

Comment: Simply put, do not expose services on the Internet unless you have to. And if you have to, whitelist the IP addresses that really need to connect. The current setup may be harmless right now but a vulnerability may be found one day, that would bypass the need for credentials. At the very least this is information disclosure. Good defense is about minimizing the possible attack surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple downsides:

- **Remote access**

This is the most basic one. If the attacker gets the credentials for any user of the database, it will have remote access. Not as improbable as you think. Remember that `config.php.bak`, `vars.php.old`, and so on, that someone left over? Guess what happens when the attacker uses [dirbuster](https://tools.kali.org/web-applications/dirbuster) and grabs those...

- **Bruteforce attacks**

Your IP is scanned all the time (the so-called *internet background noise*), and bots will find your Postgres installation. They will try to bruteforce credentials all the time.

- **Unknown exploits**

If any time there's an exploit on Postgres that allows remote access (like [this one](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-7546/)), attackers can gain access to the database. Chaining it to any file write capability and the attackers can gain a shell.

- **Information disclosure**

Depending on version and sub-version, the attackers can guess the distribution and kernel version your server is using. This can lead to more effective exploits.